# JavaScript doesn't run after PHP header call

Tags: javascript, php

I'm trying to redirect using PHP header/even a JavaScript work around call inside php to my clients.php webpage.

The problem is that PHP header/the work around loads the webpage flawlessly but the Javascript still isn't ran.

Additional notes is that after the header or even Javascript redirect to the page, trying to refresh the page won't have the Javascript load. Only switching between a webpage and coming back to clients.php does the Javascript actually run.

I have also tried this: [JavaScript not loading after PHP header() redirect](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45864156/javascript-not-loading-after-php-header-redirect)

but to no avail.

Here are parts of my code segmented, just because its quite lengthy.

**clients.php**

```
<!-- Bootstrap core JavaScript-->
<script src="vendor/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
<!-- Core plugin JavaScript-->
<script src="vendor/jquery-easing/jquery.easing.min.js"></script>
<!-- Page level plugin JavaScript-->
<script src="vendor/chart.js/Chart.min.js"></script>
<script src="vendor/datatables/jquery.dataTables.js"></script>
<script src="vendor/datatables/dataTables.bootstrap4.js"></script>
<!-- Custom scripts for all pages-->
<script src="js/sb-admin.min.js"></script>
<!-- Custom scripts for this page-->
<script src="js/sb-admin-datatables.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/sb-admin-charts.min.js"></script>

    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js" ty    pe="text/javascript"></script>
    <link href="../../css/toastr.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
    <script src="../../js/toastr.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
            var tmp = "<?php $tmp = $_SESSION['message_success']; echo "$tmp"; ?>";
            alert(tmp + " h");
            $( document ).ready(function() {
                    <?php
                        if($_SESSION['sysLogin'] == "success") {
                            $_SESSION['sysLogin'] = "";
                            $user = $_SESSION['user'];
                            echo "toastr.success('Welcome $user', 'User has logged in');";
                        }
                        if($_SESSION['message_success'] != "") {
                            $msg = $_SESSION['message_success'];
                            $_SESSION['message_success'] = "";
                            echo "toastr.success('$msg', 'Success!');";
                        }
                        if($_SESSION['message_error'] != "") {
                            $msg = $_SESSION['message_error'];
                            $_SESSION['message_error'] = "";
                            echo "toastr.error('$msg', 'Error!');";
                        }
                        if($_SESSION['message_warning'] != "") {
                            $msg = $_SESSION['message_warning'];
                            $_SESSION['message_warning'] = "";
                            echo "toastr.warning('$msg', 'Warning!');";
                        }
                     ?>
            });
    </script>
    </div>
    </body>

    </html>
```

**script.php**

```
  if($update_statement) {
      $_SESSION['message_success'] = "$_membername's Careplan has been successfully updated.";
      echo "<script type='text/javascript'>window.location.href = '../clients.php';</script>";
      //header("Location:". $redirect);
      //exit();
    }
```

**Note that clients.php and script.php are not in the same file.**

**Per Riggs request**

```
<?php
session_start();
$message="";
if(isset($_POST["login"])) {
    $redirect = NULL;
    if($_POST['redirect'] != '') {
        $redirect = $_POST['redirect'];
    }
    if(empty($_POST['username']) || empty($_POST['password'])) {
        $message = "Both fields must be filled out.";
        $_SESSION['sysLogin'] = "$message";
        header("location: ../login.php?redirect=" . urlencode($redirect));
    } else {

        require('server_connection.inc');
        $connection = connect_to_db(DB_SERVER, DB_UN, DB_PWD, DB_NAME);

        $user=mysqli_real_escape_string($connection, $_POST['username']);
        $pass=mysqli_real_escape_string($connection, $_POST['password']);
        $statement = "select * from Credentials where UserName='$user' AND Password='$pass';";
        $result = $connection->query($statement);

        if($result->num_rows == 1) {
            // lets determine the type of user that logged in
            // if not employee but CEO, Manager, ETC, its an Admin
            $employeeid = ($result->fetch_assoc())["EmployeeID"];
            $check = "select Employees.Position, Employees.Name, Employees.ID from Credentials, Employees where (Credentials.EmployeeID = Employees.ID) AND Employees.ID = '$employeeid';";
            $result_two = $connection->query($check);
            if($result->num_rows == 1) {
                $the_row = $result_two->fetch_assoc();
                if($the_row["Position"] == "Employee") {
                    $name = $the_row["Name"];
                    $the_id = $the_row['ID'];
                    $_SESSION['logon'] = true;
                    $_SESSION['user'] = "$name";
                    $_SESSION['type'] = "employee";
                    $_SESSION['sysLogin'] = "success";
                    $_SESSION['user_id'] = $the_id;
                    mysqli_close($conection);
                    if($redirect) {
                          header("Location:". $redirect);
                    } else {
                        header("location: ../index.php");
                    }
                    exit();
                } else if($the_row["Position"] == "CEO" || $the_row["Position"] == "Manager") {
                    $name = $the_row["Name"];
                    $the_id = $the_row['ID'];
                    $_SESSION['logon'] = true;
                    $_SESSION['user'] = "$name";
                    $_SESSION['type'] = "admin";
                    $_SESSION['sysLogin'] = "success";
                    $_SESSION['user_id'] = $the_id;
                    mysqli_close($conection);
                    if($redirect) {
                            header("Location:". $redirect);
                    } else {
                        header("location: ../index.php");
                    }
                    exit();
                }
            } else {
                $message = "Unable to Parse Employee. Please contact your sites Administrator.";
                $_SESSION['sysLogin'] = "$message";
                mysqli_close($conection);
                header("location: ../login.php?redirect=" . urlencode($redirect));
            }
        } else if($result->num_rows == 0){
            $message = "Incorrect username or password";
            $_SESSION['sysLogin'] = "$message";
            mysqli_close($conection);
            header("location: ../login.php?redirect=" . urlencode($redirect));
        } else {
            $message = "Database Login Error. Too many retrieved accounts. Please contact your sites Administrator.";
            $_SESSION['sysLogin'] = "$message";
            mysqli_close($conection);
            header("location: ../login.php?redirect=" . urlencode($redirect));
        }
    }
}

function write_to_log($message) {
    $file = fopen("logfile.txt", "w") or die("Unable to open file!");
    fwrite($file, "$message\n");
    fclose($file);
}

function connect_to_db($server, $username, $pwd, $dbname) {
    $conn = mysqli_connect($server, $username, $pwd);
    if(!$conn) {
            echo "" . mysqli_error($conn);
            exit;
    }
    $dbh = mysqli_select_db($conn, $dbname);
    if(!$dbh) {
        echo "" . mysqli_error($conn);
        exit;
    }
    return $conn;
}
?>
```

**This script merely links session while also checking for the login validity of the user**

The message passing does indeed work with headers to another file 'dashboard.php' but redirecting from script.php to dashboard.php doesn't yield the message, thus an implication still arises.

Comment: This may be a silly question but...  Are you sure it gets into the if statement?

Comment: I DONT SEE A `session_start()` anywhere in the code

Comment: Add [error reporting](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/845021/how-to-get-useful-error-messages-in-php/845025#845025) to the
top of your file(s) _while testing_ right after your opening PHP tag for example
`<?php error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);` to see if it yields anything.

Comment: Or simply look at your php error logs

Comment: Also, you have to be sure that there is no output before the call to `header()`. Unexpected error messages or even one space before `<?php` will stop it from working.

Comment: @jotaelesalinas What you mean output like the first 19 lines in that script. All of which are being output to the browser !??

Comment: @RiggsFolly The session on both scripts is started through an include script with the name login_script.php.

Comment: @NoobishPro It has to since its being redirected. I purposely disabled the other redirects just to view this segment.

Comment: @KyleJ I mean in `script.php`. If there is just one byte sent to the browser before the call to `header()`, it won't work.

Comment: Then show us that script as well. We are not clarevoyant

Comment: @RiggsFolly The error reporting simply reports Undefined index: being reported on my variables to insert into the db. No actual errors though.

Comment: Which index is undefined?

Comment: @RiggsFolly Various variables through post, going to clean up them and report back if they weren't the issue.

Comment: @RiggsFolly Undefined index is cleaned but the problem persists.

Answer (score 1):

The tmp JavaScript variable is not being defined since you haven't started the session. Include `session_start();` at the top of your code.

```html
<?php session_start(); ?>
<!-- Bootstrap core JavaScript-->
<script src="vendor/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
<!-- Core plugin JavaScript-->
<script src="vendor/jquery-easing/jquery.easing.min.js"></script>
<!-- Page level plugin JavaScript-->
<script src="vendor/chart.js/Chart.min.js"></script>
<script src="vendor/datatables/jquery.dataTables.js"></script>
<script src="vendor/datatables/dataTables.bootstrap4.js"></script>
<!-- Custom scripts for all pages-->
<script src="js/sb-admin.min.js"></script>
<!-- Custom scripts for this page-->
<script src="js/sb-admin-datatables.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/sb-admin-charts.min.js"></script>

    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js" ty    pe="text/javascript"></script>
    <link href="../../css/toastr.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
    <script src="../../js/toastr.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
            var tmp = "<?php $tmp = $_SESSION['message_success']; echo "$tmp"; ?>";
            alert(tmp + " h");
            $( document ).ready(function() {
                    <?php
                        if($_SESSION['sysLogin'] == "success") {
                            $_SESSION['sysLogin'] = "";
                            $user = $_SESSION['user'];
                            echo "toastr.success('Welcome $user', 'User has logged in');";
                        }
                        if($_SESSION['message_success'] != "") {
                            $msg = $_SESSION['message_success'];
                            $_SESSION['message_success'] = "";
                            echo "toastr.success('$msg', 'Success!');";
                        }
                        if($_SESSION['message_error'] != "") {
                            $msg = $_SESSION['message_error'];
                            $_SESSION['message_error'] = "";
                            echo "toastr.error('$msg', 'Error!');";
                        }
                        if($_SESSION['message_warning'] != "") {
                            $msg = $_SESSION['message_warning'];
                            $_SESSION['message_warning'] = "";
                            echo "toastr.warning('$msg', 'Warning!');";
                        }
                     ?>
            });
    </script>
    </div>
    </body>

    </html>
```

Answer (score 0):

To my surprise, the issue wasn't with the Javascript at all nor positioning like the thread posted suggested. Rather the issue seemed to have been with my PHP and calling $_membersname.

For advice to trouble shoot this later on, make sure no errors are outputted, even if PHP doesn't find any. This is from a variable that hasn't be declared.